# ¿como puedo solucionar el problema del "fetch api cannot load" y el "uncaught(in promise) TypeError"?

Tags: json

no sé que puede estar mal,necesito una ayuda con esto:
el archivo persona.json:

```
[
  {
    "nombre" : "juan",
    "cargo"  : "programador"
  },
  {
    "nombre"  : "jose",
    "cargo"   : "arquitecto"
  },
  {
    "nombre"  : "luis",
    "cargo"   : "desarrollador"
  }
]
```

luego mi archivo js esta así:

```
document.getElementById('btnjson').addEventListener('click', cargarJson);

function cargarJson(){
  fetch('personas.json')
  .then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
  })
```

1ro quiero verlo en el console del navegador.

Comment: Si el archivo persona.json empieza por [ ] (array) está mal formado. Un fichero json siempre debe empezar por corchetes { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vayamos por partes, lo primero seria desde donde estas cargando los datos en formato json. Si los tienes en el mismo archivo que el código js deberías guardarlos en una variable.

```
let data =[
  {
    "nombre" : "juan",
    "cargo"  : "programador"
  },
  {
    "nombre"  : "jose",
    "cargo"   : "arquitecto"
  },
  {
    "nombre"  : "luis",
    "cargo"   : "desarrollador"
  }
];
```

La otra opción es cargar el `json` desde un archivo externo, se puede hacer de distintas maneras, un ejemplo con solo `js` podría ser este:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

El `console.log` te mostrara los datos del json.

Una vez hayas cargado los datos en una variable los podras mostrar los datos de distintas maneras. Te lo muestro en los siguientes ejemplos:

`console.log(data)`

> Array(3)
>
> 0: {nombre: "juan", cargo: "programador"}
>
> 1: {nombre: "jose", cargo: "arquitecto"}
>
> 2: {nombre: "luis", cargo: "desarrollador"}

`console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))`

> [
>     {
>       "nombre": "juan",
>       "cargo": "programador"
>     },
>     {
>       "nombre": "jose",
>       "cargo": "arquitecto"
>     },
>     {
>       "nombre": "luis",
>       "cargo": "desarrollador"
>     }
>   ]

Por ultimo puedes ir *navegando* por el json y mostrar los datos que tu elijas.

```
for(let i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let dato = data[i];
    //Dos formas de acceder al dato
    //1.
    console.log(dato["nombre"]);
    console.log(dato.cargo);
}
```

Comment: Hola lombarda,quisiera obtener los datos del archivo json a traves de un archivo app.js la cual va así:
document.getElementById('btnjson').addEventListener('click', cargarJson);

function cargarJson(){
  fetch('personas.json')
  .then(function(res){
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(data){
    let html='';
    data.forEach(function(persona){
      html +=´
            <li>${persona.nombre} ${persona.cargo}</li>
      ´;
    })
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML  = html;
  })
}
y el resultado quisiera mostrarlo en un archivo html.Gracias.

Comment: @Jose_26 ¿Has probado el código de la respuesta?¿Que es lo que te falla o lo que no entiendes? El objetivo es que aprendas como manejar archivos json y que la respuesta pueda abarcar a la mayor cantidad de personas posibles. De forma que no he querido ser totalmente especifico. Te he mostrado como recoger los datos y como mostrarlos, puedo seguir ayudandote pero tienes que ser mas especifico en que es lo que estas fallando